# Azure Media Player - Continue the Playback Where Left Off

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, model-view-controller, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I was wondering does Azure Media Player has some Netflix-like continue the playback where left off feature or plugin, do implement into the my MVC app?

Answer (score 1):

you need to record the previous time somewhere(*) and then by setting currentTime after the playing event (after the source is set) you should have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you can simply make a plugin or script it up to cache the current position for the user by Video ID into a cloud database. When user logs back in or returns to the video, just request the video-id, user-id combination and check the last known position value. Move the current position of the player ahead if it exists.